# Laravel 6 PHPUnit Testing - could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, sqlite, phpunit

I'm started to write tests in Laravel. My application works, I can login, run migrations, but when I'm trying to test the login, I'm getting the following error:

> could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)

My DB is in Postgres, and my test is as follows:

```
/** @test */
public function user_login_ok()
{
    $response = $this->json('POST', '/api/login', [
       'email' => 'test@test.com',
       'password' => 'test'
    ]);

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

I'm not worried (for now) if my test is good enough or even right, but to solve this error.

Comment: Do you have an environment file specifically for testing, or are there some configuration options for the database in phpunit.xml `php` section? If yes, these settings could be trying to use a database connection you do not have set up.

Comment: That solved it many thanks!

Comment: No problem. I added an answer with my comment contents for future question visitors. Feel free to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a testing environment specific `.env` file?
Do you have `php` section environment configuration in your `phpunit.xml` file?

If either of these has configuration for your database connection, they should be reviewed to make sure they are configured correctly.

Answer (score 10):

You may need to enable extension for `pdo_sqlite` in your php.ini file that is being used by phpunit.

Answer (score 0):

In your phpunit.xml file (probably in the project root) you will see the following settings at the end

```
<php>
  <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
  <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
  <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
  <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
  <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
  <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
  <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
  <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
  <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
</php>
```

Change the line

```
<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
```

For the type of database you are using, in my case it is mysql

```
<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
```

To be sure of the type of database you are using, look at your .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
```